# Replace two "words" in a string using str_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

In `PHP` using `str_replace` how is possible replace two words in a string with only one word (in my case is space and not word) ?

With javascript i used:

```
string.replace(/word-|-/g," ");
```

so i want replace this two words:

```
 /word-
 -/
```

But how is possible in php ? i tried to use also

```
 preg_replace(array('/word-','-/')," ",$string);
```

but nothing :( i hope you can help me

Comment: So you want to replace `word-` and `-`, is that correct? I think  `str_replace(array('word-', '-'), ' ', $string)` should do it. Your `preg_replace` has the delimiters split.

Comment: no i want replace /word and -/

Comment: `/word-|-/` looks for `word-` **OR** `-`. it does NOT look for a literal `/` in the text, because that `/` is the regex delimiter. If you want to look for a literal slash in the text, you'd need `/\/word-|-\//`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
str_replace(array('/word-', '-/'), ' ', $string);
```

should work for you. The `/`s in the JS example though are delimiters showing where the regex starts and ends. So in the PHP `preg_replace` you'd need to do:

```
preg_replace(array('~/word-~','~-/~')," ",$string);
```

or maybe simpler:

```
preg_replace('~(/word-|-/)~'), " ",$string);
```

Note the above matches what you've stated but not what your JS is doing.